# Log in database Connection failed

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm using `Symfony 5` on my website. To authenticate users I'm using the **LDAP** Security bundle dedicated for that. It's works well

What I would like is to log in the database all client connections failed. 
With a custom LDAP Provider and User Checker, I'm able to catch :

- LockedException
- DisabledException
- AccountExpiredException
- CredentialsExpiredException
- UsernameNotFoundException

What I would like is to catch invalid credential but I don't find where this exception is throw...

For you:

1. Where can I catch invalid password exception please?
2. Where is the easiest method to overwrite to catch all security exceptions please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get all this exceptions via the custom access denied handler. (parent exception)

```
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authorization\AccessDeniedHandlerInterface;

class AccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException)
    {
        // ...

        return new Response($content, 403);
    }
}
```

-

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
firewalls:
    # ...

    main:
        # ...
        access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
```

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html for more info.